# How to optimize jetty web application with NIO?

Tags: java, optimization, jetty

I have a jetty 7 based web app which is using up the CPU and has high response times. I want to know Where to target my optimization efforts. I collected an hprof report and it shows that most of the time is spent in EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait.

```
1 31.66% 31.66%  291140 301140 sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait
2 16.18% 47.84%  148814 300461 java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept
3  8.11% 55.95%   74583 301321 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0
4  6.82% 62.77%   62703 301521 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0
5  5.27% 68.04%   48467 301492 sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0
6  3.53% 71.57%   32481 301561 java.net.SocketInputStream.read
7  3.38% 74.95%   31072 301695 sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully
8  3.30% 78.26%   30390 301733 sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read
```

The traces are shown below, I am not looking for an exact answer just pointers to what to look at by someone more familiar with Jetty internals.

```
TRACE 301140:
sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(EPollArrayWrapper.java:Unknown line)
sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:228)
sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:83)
sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)

TRACE 300461:
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(PlainSocketImpl.java:Unknown line)
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:375)
java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:470)
java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:438)

TRACE 301321:
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java:Unknown line)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:146)
sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:312)
sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:350)

TRACE 301521:
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java:Unknown line)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:146)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)

TRACE 301492:
sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:Unknown line)
sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:163)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$2.run(SelectChannelConnector.java:287)
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:451)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ignore the IO blocking calls as these do not consume CPU. (They consume a little but far less than the timing might indicate)

This includes epollWait, socketAccept, socketRead0, accept0, read, write

This leaves calls to SSL.  Given this is a CPU intensive task, its not surprising that it would be a significant CPU consumer.

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting something here, but looking at [readFully()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/ssl/InputRecord.java) it seems to me that's purely IO related either and not the actual encryption task.

Comment: The readFully may or may not be mostly IO.  I suspect its CPU all the same.

Comment: But where would be the CPU intense part when it's only looping and a `s.read(b, off + n, len - n);` call from an InputStream? I assume the input stream could be a special one that decrypts data on the fly, hmm